# Estimating bruteforce progression

Tags: math, probability, brute-force

I'm using a bruteforce algorithm to generate hashes until I find one with a defined prefix.

For example, I'm hashing random numbers until I find a hash starting with `abc12` (the hashes are hexadecimal).

I understand that for every hash, the probability to succeed is `p = (1 / (16 ^ len(prefix))`.

What I'm struggling to do is giving an approximation of the progression, as I don't know the formulas to use.

For example, I would like to say that my progression is 37%, or that I'll reach 50% after 15 minutes, or any other kind of useful information

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have some method of guaranteeing that your "random numbers" have no repetition? If your random numbers are independent, your probability on each attempt is exactly the same, and a progression bar would therefore be misleading. Each attempt would not bring you any closer to your goal.

Comment: Increment a number each iteration. 1 / p = approximatively max number of guess. You take the number of iteration and divide it by the max number of guess. You multiply by 100 and you have your approximate progression percentage.

Comment: @rm4 You could easily reach a progression larger than 100%, and that would be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an anwser

If my probability of finding a solution is 256 (prefix of length 2), then my progression is:

`1 - (255/256)^(number of attempts)`

I can estimate when I'll reach 50% by solving N in :
`1 - (255/256)^N = 1/2`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no meaningful measure of "progress" for this problem. Let's make a simple analogy:

Flip a coin repeatedly until you get heads.

What is your progress after 1, 2, or 3 tail flips?

By the reasoning in your answer it is 50%, 75% and 87.5%. But this doesn't make sense, because after each tails [we are exactly as far away from getting heads as we were when we started](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness). It will always take you 2 more flips on average to get heads.

What you might consider is computing the expected number of hashes needed to find a hash with the desired prefix. This only needs to be computed once, because it does not change based on how many you have tried in the past. In other words if you expect you need 1M hashes, this does not change whether you have tried 0 so far or 10M so far. You still need 1M more on average in either case.

The expected number of hashes is just the inverse of the probability of success:

```
E_num_hashes = 16^len_prefix
```